# Motor mount went

Tags: engine, ford, fiesta, motor-mounts

Aftermarket rear motor mount went on my Fiesta. Reason I knew right away was driving along a lot more vibration and banging on downshifts.

As I pulled up, 2 miles later, I left the car overnight and came back the next day to jack it up. Turns out the bushes had split and indeed the rear motor mount had failed badly to the point I actually couldn't drive the car that night even if I wanted to. Any gear the car would struggle bad to move hence leaving it and getting a lift home.

Having said that, what should I look out for (external damage wise) after this? I've replaced with stock mount and all seems fine, but wondering what I should visually inspect for.

Comment: When replacing those bushes they have to be fitted in the correct direction otherwise they fail early.

Comment: They were professionally fitted, it seems the bush materials are under investigation and they are supplying a harder material. I'm just not sure if any other damage may have been caused due to excess engine movement. Albeit only 2 or so miles I drove to safely park, the banging and vibrations were quite violent and the engine was moving a lot when inspected.

Comment: Aftermarket parts are usually cheap for a reason... having to buy quality ones and pay for repeat labor makes them more expensive.

Comment: That's a fair point. Luckily I do not need repeat labour as I was able to fit these myself no issues after the fact. Ty for your input though!